# Scaling image to suit 480dpi Android screen(xxhdpi)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png, android, dpi

I am newbie designer. Have designed the screens for an android app using illustrator and measurements are in pixels. My developers have asked me to provide the images @480DPI. My online research did not provide a straightforward answer so would like to hear from an expert who have done this before. My research says to make the images suitable all I have to do is scale it 300% in other words if the image is 30 by 30 pixels then make it 90 by 90 pixels. is this correct? if not what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy tool for this to help us designers.
It's called "**Android Pixel calculator**" and you can find it [here](http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/).
The use is very intuitive.

- Select, on the left, the tile of the size you need ( dp,sp,px,mm,pt,in)
- Insert in the input box the value you want to convert
- Select the right dpi from the drop down menu
- Check in the tiles the converted value

A piece of cake.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro. That confirms 300% scaling is all I need to do to make the image suitable for a 480DPI screen.